# duplicate symbol while adding a static library to a Xcode project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to add [this photo browser library](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser) to our project. I am following **Method 2: Static Library** in the *readme.md* file. Basically, it is very standard steps for adding static libraries in Xcode. Things work out fine if I create a simple *hello world* project. However, when I add the library to our existing project, we get the following **duplicate symbol** error.

Here is an example of the error (there are a lot more but they all looks similar):

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_MBBarProgressView in:
    /Users/.../Build/Intermediates/PDFMaps.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Project Name.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MBProgressHUD.o
    /Users/.../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libMWPhotoBrowser.a(MBProgressHUD.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MBBarProgressView in:
    /Users/.../Build/Intermediates/PDFMaps.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Project Name.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MBProgressHUD.o
    /Users/.../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libMWPhotoBrowser.a(MBProgressHUD.o)
```

It seems that duplications always occur between the **Intermediates** folder and the **Products** folder. Could anyone explain why is this happening and how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the logs it looks like the **MWPhotoBrowser library** has a class with name **MBProgressHUD**
https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser/tree/master/MWPhotoBrowser/Libraries/MBProgressHUD

and also another target in your project hierarchy **PDFMaps** also has the same name class causing the duplicate symbol error.

Fix is to either **rename** either one of the classes or **reuse** MBProgressHUD, whatever works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

I usually see this when one of two things happen:

- I've added the header and/or implementation to my project twice
- You have a bad merge in your xcodeproj file that has the symbol showing up more than once.

Here's what I typically do:

1. Close Xcode. Open up the xcodeproj in a text editor
2. Remove all traces of your something.h and something.m files
3. Save and reopen Xcode
4. Re-add your header and implementation, checking the applicable targets
5. Build